# Is there a way not to run unit test when starting mvn appengine:devserver?

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, junit

Each time I run `mvn appengine:devserver` the `JUnit` tests are re-run. Is there a way to avoid this testing phase? I thought it was AppEngine specific but looking at the answers I see it may not be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
mvn appengine:devserver -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

which skips building the test artifacts.

Or

```
mvn appengine:devserver -DskipTests
```

which produces test artifact, but the tests don't run.